# Some bugs in LuaHBTeX or LuaOTFload with mode=harf?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, luatex, luaotfload, harftex

Please try the following MWEs with LuaHBTeX:

```
% Plain LuaHBTeX
\input luaotfload.sty

\font\twentyfiverm="MinionPro-Regular.otf:%
   mode=harf;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig" at%
   \directlua{tex.print(10*1.2^5)} pt% PROBLEM with Minion and mode=harf!

%\font\twentyfiverm="MinionPro-Regular.otf:%
%mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig" at%
%\directlua{tex.print(10*1.2^5)} pt% mode=node OK!

%\font\twentyfiverm="lmroman10-regular.otf:%
%mode=harf;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig" at%
%\directlua{tex.print(10*1.2^5)} pt% mode=harf with Latin Modern OK!

\baselineskip\directlua{tex.print(10*1.2^6)}pt
\twentyfiverm

\font\twentyfivemath="latinmodern-math.otf:mode=base;script=math" at%
   \directlua{tex.print(10*1.2^5)} pt

\textfont1=\twentyfivemath

\Umathcode`+="2"1`+
\Umathcode`-="2"1`−
\Umathcode`±="2"1`±
\Umathcode`=="3"1`=
\Umathcode`(="4"1`(     \Udelcode`(="1`(
\Umathcode`)="5"1`)     \Udelcode`)="1`)
\Umathcode`="7"1`     \let\Bbbi=

Die Addition von komplexen Zahlen:
%
$$ a + b ± (c + d) = a ± c + (b ± d) $$% PROBLEM!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
%
Multiplikation:% this word is gobbled!
%
$$ (a + b)(c + d) = ac - bd + (ad + bc) $$

\bye
```

As shown in the picture, the word "Multiplikation" is gobbled. What is wrong? In bigger documents with many formulae LuaHBTeX even crashes without any error message but only when I use Minion as the textfont with `mode=harf`.
[image]

When I change the mode into `mode=node` or when I change the font into `lmroman10-regular` the missing word appears.

Here is another MWE. It compares the math typesetting with the options `mode=harf` (wrong) and `mode=base`(OK).

```
% Plain LuaHBTeX
\input luaotfload.sty

\font\twentyfiverm="lmroman10-regular.otf:%
mode=harf;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig" at%
\directlua{tex.print(10*1.2^5)} pt
\baselineskip\directlua{tex.print(10*1.2^6)}pt
\twentyfiverm

\font\twentyfivemath="latinmodern-math.otf:mode=harf;script=math" at%
   \directlua{tex.print(10*1.2^5)} pt

\textfont1=\twentyfivemath

\Umathcode`3="7"1`3
\Umathcode`4="7"1`4

WRONG (mode=harf):
$$ 3 \over 4 $$

\font\twentyfivemath="latinmodern-math.otf:mode=base;script=math" at%
\directlua{tex.print(10*1.2^5)} pt

\textfont1=\twentyfivemath

OK (mode=base):
$$ 3 \over 4 $$

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: Can't look now but if you think you have a bug https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload is better place to report it than here.

Comment: OK, I have done this.

Comment: https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/issues/141